# Stored Procedure result show correctly on DEV server but not on STAGING

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-server-2017

I have `DEV` and `STAGING` servers. `DEV` is a different box than the others. This code works perfectly on `DEV`. On `STAGING` it always returns zero for both `hCount` and `vCount`. 
**-- BEGIN EDIT**
I tried the suggestions in the comments to no avail. The stored procedure does include a call to an extended system stored procedure

```
EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist @FileName, @File_Exists OUT
```

I did a bit of research on xp_fileexist and found this, "*Before you begin implementation of this extended stored procedure into your applications, you will need to be aware of the security issues. When executing xp_fileexist (as well as other extended stored procedures), you will have the same rights and permissions as whichever NT account is configured to start SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER service). This account is generally either an administrator or system account. In either case, you pose a substantial security risk if you don't lock down the extended stored procedure to not allow your non-sa users to execute it.*"

I'm guessing this is where the problem lies. I'm looking into it.
**-- END EDIT**

When I run the stored procedure on the `STAGING` box in SQL Server 2017 separately from the web server, it returns the correct results:

```
exec [uDocCounts] 1, 'all', @Path, 0, 3, ''
```

My guess is the issue is with the communication between the web server and SQL Server.

EDIT: This deals with files/documents uploaded to server from application.

To further complicate matters, every page and stored procedure work fine on **STAGING**.

**STAGING** server:

- Windows Server 2016 Version 1607
- IIS Version 10.0.14393.0
- SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.2027.2)

**DEV** server:

- Windows 10 Pro
- IIS Express
- SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.1000.169)

Code:

```
// COUNT THE DOCUMENTS
var query = "uDocCounts";  // Stored procedure name

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", uID);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", ty);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", MySession.Current.DocPath);
com.Parameters.Add("@countHidden", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
com.Parameters.Add("@countVisible", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
com.Parameters.Add("@words", SqlDbType.VarChar, size: 128).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

var iError = com.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
iError.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

com.ExecuteNonQuery();

var intError = iError.Value;

if ((int)intError == 0)
{
    var hCount = com.Parameters["@countHidden"].Value.ToString();
    var vCount = com.Parameters["@countVisible"].Value.ToString();
    var words = com.Parameters["@words"].Value.ToString();

    lblCounts.Text = "There are " + hCount + " hidden documents and " + vCount + " visible ones";
    lblCounts.Visible = true;
}
```

From the STAGING SQL Server 2016 :

[image: Running stored procedure on Staging]

Comment: Your tag says SQL Server 2016 (and you also mention it in your explanation) - yet in the feature list, you define both dev and staging servers to be running SQL Server **2017** (**v14.x.x.x**) - so which is it now really?

Comment: Any chance of seeing the stored procedure code? Nothing seems to be wrong with the way you call it, so the issue must be there.

Comment: As mentioned here https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/, could you modify your program to use Add instead of AddWithValue. Please post your observations after doing so.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Does your procedure, when passed the same parameter values, return the correct resultset / output parameters when executed using SSMS in both environments?  And something looks off - your SSMS image shows the use literals for the output parms. That should generate an error.

Comment: Marc, I apologize. Its SQL 2017 v14.xxx

Comment: -sMor Yes, it returns the correct values from the SMSS in both environments. I changed to using variables for the output when calling and it still worked fine.

Comment: @sam Those are output variables using the Add, the input variables use the AddWithValue.

Comment: @Gregbert could you try changing input variables to use Add instead of AddWithValue as you are sending a string (path) value to stored proc

Comment: @sam I did with no change in the results

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to include the suggestions you tried from the comments.